# Nullpointer Exception on null check statement

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

How is the null check statement below throwing a Nullpointer Exception? Is the request perhaps null? I'm confused Somebody help.

```
if(!getTGTid(request).equalsIgnoreCase(null) || 
!getTGTid(request).equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
```

Method

```
private String getTGTid(HttpServletRequest request) {
return request.getParameter("tgtId"); 
}
```

Comment: The context is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

If `getTGTid(request)` is null, `getTGTid(request).equalsIgnoreCase(null)` will throw `NullPointerException`.

Use

```
if (getTGTid(request) != null && !getTGTid(request).equalsIgnoreCase(""))
```

Comment: Thanks Eran, will try that.